# (RDO Mod) How do you figure out how good a relationship with an NPC is/how to improve a relationship?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

In TES: Skyrim (Special Edition) with the [Relationship Dialogue Overhaul mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1187/?), how do you figure out how well a relationship is with an NPC? I am trying to marry Lydia with the RDO mod but I do not know how well she is into my character. If I need to, how do I improve my relationship with her using the RDO mod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without console commands, the only way to see an NPCs disposition toward you is through their dialogue. Most NPCs begin with a score of 0, an acquaintance, and increase/decrease based on your dialogue choices. The console command to set an NPC to "like" you is `getrelationshiprank player 4`. You can then set them to be married to you by using the command `addtofaction 19809 1`. The command console is only available on PC.

Howver, with the RDO mod, NPCs will tend to use the friendlier dialogue options towards you if they are friendly with you. Read the dialogue options and keep picking what you think is best.

RDO also provides an alternative to dialogue options through its mod configuration menu. The menu is available if you are using SkyUI. From the MCM menu, you can alter an NPCs disposition or relationship with you, including making someone your spouse.

Comment: Is there any alternative to SkyUI's MCM menu because SKSE is not out yet and SkyUI is not in development for SSE?

Comment: I don't think so. SKSE will be a while before release and SkyUI will not be getting a SSE edition.

Comment: Lydia for me only has basic dialogue choices that wouldn't increase her relationship with me. Do I just bring her with me on quests to increase her relationship without console commands?

Comment: I forgot to ask, but are you wearing the amulet of Mara? That is required for marriage options in game. Also, Lydia used to be bugged and not able to be married without console commands. That was fixed in a patch but I do not know if it was reintroduced in other patches due to further bugs.

Comment: I have it, but I unequipped it. I'll equip it and talk to her occasionally.